# Why does an empty canvas appear instead of my image?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I'm coding a game, and I want there to be the company logo for about 3-5 seconds before entering the game itself. Here's my code:

```
Graphics gfx = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    gfx.setColor(new Color(146, 17, 189));
    gfx.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    // Draw stuffs between here...
    gfx.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    int timer = 0;
    while (timer <= 4) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Could not put thread to sleep! :(");
        }
        timer++;
    }
    gfx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    if (key.showFPS == true) {
        //Set it up so that it still works with the "per second" rule.
        key.showPerSeconds(buffer, FPS, TPS);
    }
    // and here.
    gfx.dispose();
    buffer.show();
}
```

My main problem is that a blank JFrame appears, then after 4 seconds, the game itself appears. What's wrong with my code? Is there something I should be doing that I'm not right now?

Comment: `Graphics gfx = buffer.getDrawGraphics();`  What is `buffer`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is taking 4 seconds to paint the complete JFrame because you have a sleep of 4 seconds in your code:

```
while (timer <= 4) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be in image variable  after while loop of `Thread.sleep`.

```
gfx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
```

This image make your frame blank.